# Reading Binary File (.out) in Python and disassemble with Capstone

Tags: python, binaryfiles, capstone

I have some trouble reading the .text section of a binary file.

The binary is compiled by gcc.

```
readelf -S binary_file
```

This command shows that

```
.text   PROGBITS    0000831C   00031C   000340
```

The address if the .text section is 0000831c, offset = 00031c and size = 000340

I have tried

```
file = open('binary_file')
content = file.readlines()
```

And the Capstone could not recognize.

If the .text content looks like

```
 f102 030e 0000 a0e3
```

how to read it as

```
content = b'\xf1\x02\x03\x0e\x00\x00\xa0\xe3'
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `open()` opens a file in text mode.  To open a file in binary mode, you need to supply the appropriate mode: 'rb' - which means open for reading in binary mode.

`readlines()` is designed to read a line of text from a file, so it does not make sense to use it for reading from a binary file.

You want something like:

```
file = open('binary_file', 'rb')
content = file.read()
```